# Why does adding Gaussian noise to image give white screen?

Tags: python-3.x, image, opencv, image-processing, gaussian

I added some Gaussian noise to the image(water_coins.jpg) added below, but it returns me a completely white blank screen (for both "noi" and "hoho"). I can't figure out why

```
import numpy as np
import cv2


def gauss_noise(image):
    row, col, ch = image.shape
    mean = 0
    var = 0.01
    sigma = var ** 0.5
    gauss = np.random.normal(mean, sigma, (row, col, ch))
    gauss = gauss.reshape(row, col, ch)
    print(image)
    cv2.imshow("hoho", gauss + image)
    noisy = image + gauss
    return noisy


img = cv2.imread('water_coins.jpg')
noi = gauss_noise(img)
cv2.imshow("Noisy Gauss image", noi)
cv2.imshow("ho", img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

[image: Water_coins.jpg]

Comment: Images in float values have to be from 0-1, you add an image uint8 to an image float.... you need to do saturation (mean 0 can generate negative values) and then you have to convert it to np.uint (at least to display it) or normalize it to 0-1 values. If not, any value bigger than 1 will be displayed as white

Comment: @api55  converting to uint8 worked. Thanks

Comment: @api55 Why give an answer in a comment? I'd suggest moving your comment to an actual answer so the OP can accept it and this question can be considered answered.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart My bad, I had little time at the moment and just posted the comment. But I added it now as a complete answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that when you add an image that is of type `np.uint8` to another one which is of type float it will result in a float array. By the [documentation of imshow](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=imshow#imshow) you have that:

> If the image is 32-bit floating-point, the pixel values are multiplied by 255. That is, the value range [0,1] is mapped to [0,255].

This means that any value bigger than 1.0 will be white and only 0 will be black, in your case most of them will be white, thus a white image.

Now to the solutions:

1. Convert it to uint8 -> You have to be careful for underflow (negative numbers) and overflow (more than 255). Try a two sided truncation, and also, decide what to do with the decimal part (round, truncate, ceil).
2. Normalize the data to 0-1 -> depending on what you want to do this can be dangerous, since it may change the colors, for instance if all the colors are around 120-150 you will get in the normalized image colors as if it was from 0-255.
3. Convert the noise array to `np.uint8` before adding, and use cv2.add to avoid saturation problems (underflow and overflow)